# How to calculate gas for calling a function without deploying to mainnet?

Tags: contract-development

What is the best way to check the cost (gas) price for any given function call in a smart contract, before deployment to mainnet?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few choices:

- Use [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=false&version=soljson-v0.4.25+commit.59dbf8f1.js) IDE, it allows you to simulate a chain
- Use a test network like [ropsten](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/) or [rinkeby](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/). They are like main network, but ether is free and it is used, as their names state it, as test networks.

Comment: Thanks, I use Remix and Rinkeby already. Was just wondering if there were any better solution ...